# Find column names and their respective value in a pandas data frame which matches a condition and store the result in a dictionary

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas dataframe (called **df**) where I search for each row,(i.e. on a given date) the columns which have values less than 0.5. In the below screenshot, I have highlighted the values (in yellow) which are less than 0.5.

[image]

The **df** dataframe is as follows:

```
data = {'Date': ['2020-12-22','2020-12-23','2020-12-24','2020-12-25'],
    'A': ['0.065','0.965','0.363','0.774'],
    'B': ['0.292','0.367','0.396','0.484'],
    'C': ['0.078','0.489','0.095','0.781'],
    'D': ['0.703','0.748','0.631','0.612']}

df = config.pd.DataFrame (data, columns = ['Date','A', 'B', 'C', 'D'])
```

I would like to store the result in a dictionary which should look similar to the below nested dictionary:

[image]

Could someone help me with a sample code.

Comment: FYI, the dfs of the picture and code do not match

Comment: @IoaTzimas: Thank you for pointing it out. I have corrected all the images

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following. I understand that the res=... line is not very readable, as most of dict comprehensions are, but it's more concise. If you need a more redable solution, it can be easily done with a couple of loops-ifs

```
d=df.to_dict(orient='records')

res={i['Date']:{k:float(i[k]) for k in i if k!='Date' and float(i[k])<0.5} for i in d}

>>>print(res)

{'2020-12-22': {'A': 0.065, 'B': 0.292, 'C': 0.078}, '2020-12-23': {'B': 0.367, 'C': 0.489}, '2020-12-24': {'A': 0.363, 'B': 0.396, 'C': 0.095}, '2020-12-25': {'B': 0.484}}
```

If you want to use loops to construct the result, you can do the following:

```
d=df.to_dict(orient='records')

for i in d:
    temp={}
    for k in i:
        if k!='Date' and float(i[k])<0.5:
            temp[k]=float(i[k])
    res[i['Date']]=temp

>>>print(res)
    
{'2020-12-22': {'A': 0.065, 'B': 0.292, 'C': 0.078}, '2020-12-23': {'B': 0.367, 'C': 0.489}, '2020-12-24': {'A': 0.363, 'B': 0.396, 'C': 0.095}, '2020-12-25': {'B': 0.484}}
```

Comment: Could this be implemented by simple for loops ?

Comment: The below solution using for loops doesn't seem to add keys, instead over writes it. 

res={}

for i in d:
    for k in i:
        if k != 'Date' and float(i[k])<0.5:
            res['Date'] = {k:float(i[k])}

Comment: Hi @PrateekDaniels i added one more solution, using loops, under my original answer

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your correctly, you could use [to_dict](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_dict.html) to generate the results and filter with a dictionary comprehension:

```
import pprint

# set Date as index
n_df = df.set_index('Date').astype(float)

# use to_dict('index')
res = {k: {ki: vi for ki, vi in d.items() if vi < 0.5} for k, d in n_df.to_dict('index').items()}

pprint.pprint(res)
```

**Output**

```
{'2020-12-22': {'A': 0.065, 'B': 0.292, 'C': 0.078},
 '2020-12-23': {'B': 0.367, 'C': 0.489},
 '2020-12-24': {'A': 0.363, 'B': 0.396, 'C': 0.095},
 '2020-12-25': {'B': 0.484}}
```

Comment: Could this be implemented by simple for loops ?